# Convert strings in list to datetime resulting in ValueError: Format does not match. '"%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"'

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, datetime, type-conversion

I want to convert a list of string to a list of datetimes.

```
import datetime as dt
buffer_dates = ["01.10.2016 00:00", "01.10.2016 00:10", "01.10.2016 00:20", "01.10.2016 00:30", "01.10.2016 00:40", "01.10.2016 00:50"]
timestamps = [dt.datetime.strptime(date, '"%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"').date() for date in buffer_dates]
```

Resulting in ->  ValueError: time data '01.10.2016 00:00' does not match format '"%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"'

Your help is greatly appreciated! Btw. I am using python 2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a simple mistake, change 
`'"%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"'`
to 
`"%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"`.

I checked, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this answer to provide some further information regarding the error. As Mohammad pointed out, the doble apostrophes `"` are inferred within the format, so there is no need to specify them within the format. 
From python's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

> Conversely, the datetime.strptime() class method creates a datetime object from a string representing a date and time and a corresponding format string.

This means that the function's behaviour is to infer that a string is being passed. Therefore the format should not contain extra apostrophes to express that a string is being passed.

Finally, as Mohammad said: `"%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"` is enough.